# how to print this pattern in php?

Tags: php, html

[image: print this pattern within html table in php]

I run this program, but I need the output within table.  So would you please solve this?

```
<?php 
$s="*";
for($b=1; $b<=5; $b++) {
  for($c=5; $c>=$b-1; $c--) {
    if($c>=$b) {
      echo $s;
    }
    else if($b != 1) {
      echo "  ";
    }
  }
  for($d=5; $d>=$b; $d--) {
    echo $s;
  }
  echo "<br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you asking us to code this for you? What have you tried?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a programming service. Show us what you have tried so far, tell us where you are stuck at and then ask a specific question which we can answer to help you to proceed.

Comment: Instead of just printing out a `*`, you probably want to print `<td>*</td>` with a `<tr>` for each new row.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a site when you can bring code to debug OR even get code for free. It is a problem discussing page in which you give information of what you have tried so far , and what problems you have come across , and get solution for those problems . Give us what you have tried so far , please!

Comment: I know to create html tables.but here I cant include table within loop.so if anybody know how to add table within loops,reply me.help me to solve this .

Comment: Add the `<tr>`s within loops within a `<table>`, then post a working example with a URL we can see if you are still stuck.

Answer (score 2):

If you're fine regardless of how the code was written (only results matter), you can use this:

```
print('<table>');
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
{
    print('<tr>');
    for ($j = 1; $j <= 5; $j++)
    {
        print('<td>');
        (5 - $i >= $j) ? print('*') : '';
        print('</td>');
    }

    for ($j2 = 1; $j2 <= 5; $j2++)
    {
        print('<td>');
        (1 + $i <= $j2) ? print('*') : '';
        print('</td>');
    }
    print('</tr>');
}
print('</table>');
```

What I did there is I sliced table in half vertically and used 2 for loops to fill left and right halfs. You will get something like this:

[image]